# Define whole column in API range specification

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I can use below syntax to refer whole column A,B and C:

```
A1:C
```

Below script will refer to full available cells!

```
  var myRange = {
    'sheetId': sheet.getSheetId(),
    'startRowIndex': 0,
    'endRowIndex': sheet.getLastRow(),
    'startColumnIndex': 0,
    'endColumnIndex': sheet.getLastColumn()
  }
```

If user insert a new line, this range will not cover it. How to change it to support whole column just like `A1:C`?

Full script as below:

```
function addConditonalFormat() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules()
  var colorMerged = {'red': 222/255, 'green': 235/255, 'blue': 246/255, 'alpha': 0.7}
  var colorSkipped = {'red': 222/255, 'green': 235/255, 'blue': 0, 'alpha': 0.7}
  var myRange = {
    'sheetId': sheet.getSheetId(),
    'startRowIndex': 0,
    'endRowIndex': sheet.getLastRow(),
    'startColumnIndex': 0,
    'endColumnIndex': sheet.getLastColumn()
  }

  var config = [["merged",colorMerged],["skipped",colorSkipped]]
  var requests = []
  for (var i=0;i<config.length;i++)  {
    var row = config[i]
    var keyword = row[0]
    var color = row[1]
    Logger.log(keyword + ":" + color)
    var cond = {'addConditionalFormatRule': {
      'index': 0,
      'rule': {
      'ranges': [ myRange ],
        'booleanRule': {
          'format': {'backgroundColor': color},
          'condition': {
            'type': 'CUSTOM_FORMULA',
            'values':[{'userEnteredValue': '=$A:$A="' + keyword + '"'}]},},},}         }
    requests.push(cond)
  }  
  var format_req = {
    'requests': requests,
    'includeSpreadsheetInResponse': false,
  }
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(JSON.stringify(format_req), ss.getId())
}
```

After run the script, then insert rows after last row, the conditional format will not apply to the new added rows!

[image]

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about it? 1. About ``user insert a new line``, user puts a value to the rows below the current last row? Or user inserts new rows in the sheet? 2. About ``this range will not cover it``, how does the user put or insert? 3. ``getLastRow()`` and ``getLastColumn()`` retrieve the current last row and last column which has the value, respectively. Although I'm not sure about your whole script, for example, what result will you obtain, when ``SpreadsheetApp.flush()`` is put before ``var myRange = {}``?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks, yes, I means user append new rows after last row. full script and sample data/output updated. I no need to call flush since data input is by user.

Comment: Thank you for updating it. I could understand about your situation. I noticed that an answer had already been posted, now. It will resolve your issue. If you want to fix the last column to the column "C", please remove only ``'endRowIndex': sheet.getLastRow()``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple: to refer to the entirety of the sheet, do not supply **any** index specifications. Per the [`DimensionRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/DimensionRange) and [`GridRange`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other#GridRange) documentation, missing indices indicate an unbounded specification.

```js
const theWholeSheet = {
  sheetId: sheet.getSheetId()
};
const noFirstRowOrFirstCol = {
  sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),
  startColumnIndex: 1,
  startRowIndex: 1
};
```

Comment: Thanks, after remove the lines and apply my function, then check it from conditonal format UI, it says "A1:CW1001", I wish it's "A1:CW".

Comment: @lucky if you manually set that in the conditional format UI configuration, does it remain? Or is it also converted when you save and reopen the document?

Comment: Exactly, even if I changed it to "A1:CW" in UI, but if I reopen it, it will change to "A1:CW1001". Does that means it only handle 1001 rows as biggest range?

Comment: @lucky no, it means what you want is not possible currently. If you specify a range larger than the current sheet configuration, the current configuration is used. The solution is to periodically update your formatting